# Generics in Hamcrest Matchers

Tags: java, generics, hamcrest

I am not quite sure if the problem I am having has a simple solution, but here's the code excerpt:

```
 Map<?,?> m = dbo.toMap();
 assertThat(m, Matchers.<Object, Object>hasEntry(is(someKeyValue), is(notNullValue())));
```

I have to add those generics to appease compiler, but why can't it be any simpler? Why do I have to add wildcard capture to the `m` variable ? Why can't it be at least:

```
 assertThat(dbo.toMap(), hasEntry(is((Object)someKeyValue), is(notNullValue())));
```

Here's the [simple project](https://bitbucket.org/evgeniysharapov/hamcrest-boilerplate). In the unit test lines that bother me:

```
// this one doesn't quite work
DBObject dbo = returnSomeDBObject();
Map m3 = dbo.toMap();
assertThat(m3, hasEntry(is((Object)PSF_KEY), is(notNullValue())));

// but this one does
DBObject dbo2 = returnSomeDBObject();
Map<?,?> m4 = dbo.toMap();
assertThat(m4, Matchers.<Object, Object>hasEntry(is(PSF_KEY), is(notNullValue())));
```

Comment: Actually should work on Java 7 and 8. Show us a complete, parameterized example and how it fails (compilation error, etc.)

Comment: I added a link to a project and the code excerpt illustrating the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "raw" matcher:

```
DBObject dbo = returnSomeDBObject();
Map m3 = dbo.toMap();

assertThat(m3, (Matcher)hasEntry(is("PSF_KEY"), is(notNullValue())));
```

---

By the way, you can use the [Matchers.hasKey](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasKey%28K%29) method to assert that the map has an entry with a specific key:

```
assertThat(m3, (Matcher)hasKey("PSF_KEY"));
```

However be aware that this is not sementically the same as the first assert when dealing with `null` values in the map.